# UriComponents (mailto: vs mailto://)

Tags: email, spring-mvc, mailto, url-scheme

does this "mailto" encode is normal for you? (mailto: vs mailto://)

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("mailto://test.test@test.com?Subject=here we are ééé d'in").build();
String encodedUri = uriComponents.encode().toUriString();
System.out.println(encodedUri);

uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("mailto:test.test@test.com?Subject=here we are ééé d'in").build();
encodedUri = uriComponents.encode().toUriString();
System.out.println(encodedUri);
```

output :

```
mailto://test.test@test.com?Subject=here%20we%20are%20%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%20d'in
mailto:test.test@test.com?Subject=here we are ééé d'in
```

spring version : 4.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: What are you asking? Are you wondering if the two different encodings work? Or how the encodings differ?

Comment: the two different encodings doesnt work.just the first one is ok. i wonder if this is normal that if you use "mailto:" encoding is not perform.